# MySQL query performance: individuate and rewrite faster query

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, join

today I stumbled upon two different form of the same query (which return the very same result) but that execute in very different durations:

```
ORIGINAL QUERY:

select count(distinct unit.ID)
from UNIT unit 
    left outer join AUTHORIZATION auth on unit.ID=auth.UNIT_ID 
    left outer join WORKFLOW_EXECUTION exec on unit.WORKFLOW_EXECUTION_ID=exec.ID 
where 
(
    unit.RESPONSIBLE_ID=2
    and 
    (
        (
            unit.STATUS<>'CLOSED' 
            and 
            unit.EXPECTEDRELEASEDATE is not null
        ) 
        or 
        exec.ACTIVE=1
    )
)
or 
(
    exec.ACTIVE=1 
    and 
    auth.INTERVENTION=1 
    and 
    auth.SUBJECT_ID=2
);
```

plan:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------+--------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type   | possible_keys                                                     | key                                 | key_len | ref                              | rows   | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------+--------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | unit  | NULL       | ALL    | FK_UNIT_RESPONSIBLE_ID,IX_UNIT_STATUS,IX_UNIT_EXPECTEDRELEASEDATE | NULL                                | NULL    | NULL                             | 451486 |   100.00 | NULL        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | auth  | NULL       | ref    | UK_AUTHORIZATION_UNIT_ID_SUBJECT_ID,FK_AUTHORIZATION_UNIT_ID      | UK_AUTHORIZATION_UNIT_ID_SUBJECT_ID | 9       | edea2.unit.ID                    |      1 |   100.00 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | exec  | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                           | PRIMARY                             | 8       | edea2.unit.WORKFLOW_EXECUTION_ID |      1 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------+--------+----------+-------------+
```

duration:

```
+-------------------------+
| count(distinct unit.ID) |
+-------------------------+
|                     538 |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (2.46 sec)
```

Then, I observed that when executing this query with only one predicate of where, the duration is sensibly decreased.

So I had the idea to rewrite it in a new style:

```
select count(distinct unit_root.ID)
from UNIT unit_root 
where 
    unit_root.ID in 
    (
        select unit.ID
        from UNIT unit 
            left outer join WORKFLOW_EXECUTION exec on unit.WORKFLOW_EXECUTION_ID=exec.ID 
        where 
        (
            unit.RESPONSIBLE_ID=2
            and 
            (
                (
                    unit.STATUS<>'CLOSED' 
                    and 
                    unit.EXPECTEDRELEASEDATE is not null
                ) 
                or 
                exec.ACTIVE=1
            )
        )
    )
    or  
    unit_root.ID in 
    (
        select unit.ID
        from UNIT unit 
            left outer join WORKFLOW_EXECUTION exec on unit.WORKFLOW_EXECUTION_ID=exec.ID 
            left outer join AUTHORIZATION auth on unit.ID=auth.UNIT_ID 
        where 
        (
            exec.ACTIVE=1 
            and 
            auth.INTERVENTION=1 
            and 
            auth.SUBJECT_ID=2
        )
    );
```

plan:

```
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+----------------------------------+--------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table     | partitions | type   | possible_keys                                                                                                             | key                         | key_len | ref                              | rows   | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+----------------------------------+--------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | unit_root | NULL       | index  | PRIMARY,FK_UNIT_RESPONSIBLE_ID,FK_UNIT_WORKFLOW_EXECUTION_ID,IX_UNIT_EXPECTEDRELEASEDATE                                  | IX_UNIT_EXPECTEDRELEASEDATE | 6       | NULL                             | 451486 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
|  3 | SUBQUERY    | auth      | NULL       | ref    | UK_AUTHORIZATION_UNIT_ID_SUBJECT_ID,FK_AUTHORIZATION_UNIT_ID,FK_AUTHORIZATION_SUBJECT_ID,IX_AUTHORIZATION_INTERVENTION    | FK_AUTHORIZATION_SUBJECT_ID | 8       | const                            |      1 |    50.00 | Using where              |
|  3 | SUBQUERY    | unit      | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,FK_UNIT_WORKFLOW_EXECUTION_ID                                                                                     | PRIMARY                     | 8       | edea2.auth.UNIT_ID               |      1 |   100.00 | NULL                     |
|  3 | SUBQUERY    | exec      | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,IX_WORKFLOW_EXECUTION_ACTIVE                                                                                      | PRIMARY                     | 8       | edea2.unit.WORKFLOW_EXECUTION_ID |      1 |    26.47 | Using where              |
|  2 | SUBQUERY    | unit      | NULL       | ref    | PRIMARY,FK_UNIT_RESPONSIBLE_ID,IX_UNIT_STATUS,IX_UNIT_EXPECTEDRELEASEDATE                                                 | FK_UNIT_RESPONSIBLE_ID      | 8       | const                            | 225743 |   100.00 | NULL                     |
|  2 | SUBQUERY    | exec      | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                                                   | PRIMARY                     | 8       | edea2.unit.WORKFLOW_EXECUTION_ID |      1 |   100.00 | Using where              |
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+----------------------------------+--------+----------+--------------------------+
```

duration:

```
+------------------------------+
| count(distinct unit_root.ID) |
+------------------------------+
|                          538 |
+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.51 sec)
```

Finally, the questions:

1. Why there's such a difference? Shouldn't the optimizer be able to ptimize this kind of queries?
2. Is there a tip to quickly individuate this kind of queries without having to measure execution time or investigating query plan?
3. Any tips on how to rewite to faster style?

Note that I'm using MySQL 5.7.10 and these queries are generated by Hibernate.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have too many questions, but here is some background.

First, you are asking way too much of the optimizer.  I haven't looked through the details of your queries, but they may not be exactly the same logically.  For instance, `NULL` values or duplicate values in a table might cause differences.

Second, although it is often said (by me and many others) that SQL is a *descriptive language* and not a *procedural language*.  However, this doesn't extend to query re-writes.  It usually means that the optimizer can re-arrange joins, use indexes, choose appropriate algorithms for joins and aggregations, decide the optimal place do filtering, and a few other things.  However, the basic structure of the processing is put in place.

In terms of hints.  The use of `GROUP BY` and `DISTINCT` slow queries down.  Don't avoid them!  They are necessary parts of the language.  But as you discover in these two queries, there can be a savings.  Another danger is `OR`, because it can prevent the use of relevant indexes.

Judging by the complexity of logic in the subqueries, it might be possible to further optimize the queries.

Finally, if you want to write efficient queries, you cannot depend on the query optimizer.  You will need to put the work in to learn how the query optimizer works, as well as something about the algorithms used for different components of the query, and fundamental optimization techniques such as indexing and partitioning.

Comment: Thank you, but this is just a general advice and it doesn't really answer any specific question. Don't take it the wrong way, I know what relational algebra is and how it works, but here it's just a matter of *implementation*. I'll be grateful if you can look through the details of the original query (it's a simple one) and how I rewrote it in an *unpacked* style, obtaining a speed boost (while sacrificing readability) moving the `OR` clause from full rows to a single indexed column. continue...

Comment: I could just learn every single MySQL **specific** optimizer detail, but it isn't time-cost cheap and that's why I'm asking here. Anyway, I found out "how" it works in this specific case [Optimizing Subqueries with Semi-Join Transformations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subquery-optimization.html#semi-joins). However, thank you for your advice.